# How RabbitMQ connection works between 2+ endpoints?

Tags: java, c#, python, rabbitmq

I've looked at the tutorial for RabbitMQ RPC. The client and server basicly do the same. Assumed i've 2 or more computer who want to consume from a queue. I wonder how the know from each other if i just pass the own network hostname/ip to the ConnectionFactory. Does [this example](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-dotnet.html) work on to different machines? (Can not test because of config issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it works on different machines. If you want to connect from a different computer just pass a different Host to your ConnectionFactory.

If you can't connect from a different machine due to configuration problems, perhaps you are using the `guest:guest` user, which can only connect from localhost? https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html